# Spooky stuff happening when hovering over dropdown

Tags: html, css

im having a problem when im trying to create a dropdown.(See JSfiddle) The navigation menu is going from side to side when im hovering over it.. I have not seen any other placed that can solve my problem :/

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kavqc/2/

I think the problem is here a place:

```
.dropdown {
    position:absolute; 
    top:62px; 
    left:0; 
    visibility:hidden;
    background-color: red;
}
```

PS: sry for my bad English

Comment: I don't see anything in the fiddle?

Comment: @tymeJV - That is the point. It is haunted. There is a ghost that you cannot see without those special red glasses from a cereal box.

Comment: There's no such thing as 'float: center;'. You also need to do some homework on relative vs. absolute positioning.

Comment: You dont on this link? http://jsfiddle.net/kavqc/

Comment: You can't have `<li>` tags outside of a `<ul>` or `<ol>`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat actually technically you can have `<li>` tags outside of a `<ul>` or `<ol>`, its just not proper

Comment: @KevinJantzer: I guess you *can*, but browsers won't always render it correctly.  http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element

Comment: @RocketHazmat They will render it correctly if you override all the default styles. But of course, one **should NOT do this**

Comment: @KevinJantzer: Tell that to IE :)

Comment: @KevinJantzer,  An `<li>` outside of `<ul>`/`<ol>` is still invalid no matter how much CSS you apply.  Why would you even want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the menu jumps to the right is because of the `margin-left` style:

```
.navbar-menu:hover {
    ...
    margin-left: 200px; // remove this
    ...
 }
```

Here is your jsFiddle with the `margin-left` **removed**: http://jsfiddle.net/kavqc/3/

Comment: @user2736147 - If this answers your question, don't forget to click the check mark next to it to give Kevin credit and to mark the question as answered.

Comment: @Shauna *(the asker cannot accept any answers until the question is live for at least 15 minutes)*

Comment: @DJDavid98 - Fair enough. Was simply a polite reminder, since many new users forget about that part.

Answer (score 2):

as @KevinJantzer mentioned - fix the jump by changing margin-left.

Fix the menu positioning by adding `position: relative` to your .li class:

```
.li {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    list-style:none;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kavqc/4/)